# OR-Tools MIP Solver - Defining an objective in terms of int, instead of IntVar

Tags: python, or-tools

I am trying to define an objective function which uses the current value of a variable, as an integer, for computation (as shown below):

```
def foo(arg1, arg2, arg3):
   return arg1 - arg2 + arg3
    
def objective_that_does_not_work(x0, x1, x2):
   y = foo(x0.solution_value(), x1.solution_value(), x2.solution_value())
   return y

def objective_that_works(x0, x1, x2):
   y = foo(x0, x1, x2)
   return y
```

where x0, x1, x2 are IntVars.

In my use case, the function foo is defined in a way that it requires int arguments.

When I try and maximize `objective_that_does_not_work`, it randomly gives me either the upper bound or the lower bound for each of x0, x1, x2 (different values each time I run the solver).

My questions:

1. Is it possible to define the objective in terms of the value of the IntVar, instead of the IntVar itself?
2. If yes, is `solution_value()` the right attribute to be using? From the documentation, it seemed the most appropriate, but I may be misinterpreting its use.

Thank you

Comment: It isn't posible to know the answer before solving so you will have to write down the foo function manually

Comment: Afraid I don't follow. To my knowledge, optimizers iteratively search for the next 'best' solution so there should be a starting point (or current solution) at every step. Please let me know if my understanding of how they work is incorrect. (ref - https://acrogenesis.com/or-tools/documentation/user_manual/manual/objectives/optimization_how.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only express the objective as a linear combination of variables.